# How to compile MySQL 5.7 in Alpine Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, cmake, alpine-linux

I am trying to install MySQL 5.7 in an Alpine docker image. For now I know that MySQL does not provide any build for Alpine so I tried compiling MySQL from source.

My Dockerfile MySQL section:

```
RUN git clone -b 5.7 --single-branch https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server.git --depth=1
RUN cd mysql-server && \
    apk add cmake && \
    mkdir bld && \
    cd bld && \
    cmake .. && \
    make && \
    make install
```

But this is not working. So, my question is: Does MySQL 5.7 compiles for Alpine Linux? If yes, then how should I do that?

Comment: See: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/179

Comment: So currently there is no such thing as mysql for alpine?

Comment: [Alex Sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12532105/alex-sonar) posted in an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64835309/12695027) "I am in front of the same issue MSSQL on Alpine. I would be supposed it might be helpful. [Mysql installation for alpine linux in docker](https://github.com/woahbase/alpine-mysql)"